# How are the & and | operators evaluated in if statements without parentheses?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a practice course for Python that requests a script to calculate leap years.

Leap years have the following conditions:

- Must be a multiple of 4
- Must NOT be a multiple of 100, unless it is also a multiple of 400.

##### Attempt1

```
year = int(input("Check this year "))

leapFourYears = year % 4
leapCentury = year % 100
leapFourCenturies = year % 400

if (leapFourYears == 0 & leapCentury != 0) | leapFourCenturies == 0:
    print('leap year')
else:
    print('not leap year')
```

This works for, e.g., 2000, but it incorrectly prints 'not leap year' for, e.g., 2016.

I printed out each condition, and individually, they evaluate to true or false as expected. However, the moment I involve a & or | operator, the evaluation goes awry.

I started attaching parentheses and came upon this correct if-statement:

##### Attempt 2

```
if ((leapFourYears == 0) & (leapCentury != 0)) | (leapFourCenturies == 0):
```

This works.

Can someone explain to me how Python python parses multiple conditions with & and | operators that do not have parentheses? How is Python evaluating it that makes it work for 2000 but not 2016?

Is there a way to do this without the parentheses around each condition?

Thanks!

Python 3.8.10

Comment: use `and` and `or` not logical bitwise operators

Comment: Regardless of parenthesis or not, you are using the wrong operators. You should be using `and` and `or`, not their bitwise equivalent. Either way, it's all about [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

Comment: `if (leapFourYears == 0 & leapCentury != 0) | leapFourCenturies == 0:` => `if (not leapFourYears and leapCentury) or not leapFourCenturies:`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: @Julien thanks! Didn't know I had the wrong operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the bitwise operators, not the logical operators. Instead of

```
if ((leapFourYears == 0) & (leapCentury != 0)) | (leapFourCenturies == 0):
```

use

```
if leapFourYears == 0 and leapCentury != 0 or leapFourCenturies == 0:
```

The `and` has priority over `or`([Operator Precedence in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)).

Comment: Probably out of scope of this question/answer, but since all of these are essentially booleans I'd go with `if not leapFourYears and not leapCentury or leapFourCenturies:` for a more fluent reading/understanding, but again, this is just nitpicking.

Comment: Does and always have priority, so if I have `if c1 and c2 or c3 and c4`, it will evaluate as `(c1 and c2) or (c3 and c4)`?

Comment: @DeepSpace That's good to know, thanks!

Comment: @Blaisem Yes, see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence